# Wordpress query: category__in takes only first argument and no more

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have this code:

```
$categories = get_query_var('cat');  //now: $categories = "201";
$categories .= ",";  //now: $categories = "201,";
$sub_cats = get_categories('parent='.$categories); //grab subcategories of this main category
foreach($sub_cats as $sub_cat){ //grab term id of subcategories
$categories .= $sub_cat->term_id;
$categories .= ",";
}
//now $categories = "201,119,394,";
$categories = substr($categories, 0, -1); //now $categories = "201,119,394";


query_posts( array( 'category__in' => array( $categories ), 'meta_key' => '_single_views', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'paged' => $paged ));
```

Problem is that it return only posts in category 201 (all times only first category of $category variable).

Database query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (201)
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_single_views'
) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Where can be problem please? I need to return all posts in categories 201,119,394 (posts that are at least in one of them). Thank you for help.

Comment: The problem seems to be in get_query_var('cat'); which is outside the shown code. Also this seems to be a wordpress configuration issue only. Please remove the mysql tag.

Comment: Hi, I think that get_query_var('cat'); is correct, it is returning category ID of page where currently am I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine.

```
query_posts( array( 'cat' => $categories, 'meta_key' => '_single_views', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'paged' => $paged ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, suggestion: Either reverse the two lines:

```
$categories .= ",";  //now: $categories = "201,";
$sub_cats = get_categories('parent='.$categories);
```

Why: The categories become categories (201) becomes 201, which is then used in the parent=$categories. This fails to return anything due to the ,.

or use this alternative:

```
$categories = get_query_var('cat');  //now: $categories = "201";
$sub_cats = get_categories('parent='.$categories); //grab subcategories of this main category
foreach($sub_cats as $sub_cat){ //grab term id of subcategories
$categories .= ",".$sub_cat->term_id;
}
query_posts( array( 'category__in' => array( $categories ), 'meta_key' => '_single_views', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'paged' => $paged ));
```

P.s. is category__in correct? 2 underscores in a row might spell some more trouble.